# Eliminar consultas de base de datos con php

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Me podrian decir como eliminar una consulta desde php para mi base de datos

> 

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1" , "root" , "" , "tiendita") or die ("Error al conectar");/*conexion*/

$resultado = $conexion->query("CALL delCliente();") or die ("Hay problema con la consulta");

while ($row= $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["nombre"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["sexo"] . "</td>";
    /*echo $row[0] . " - " . $row["nombre"] . " - " . $row["sexo"] . "<hr>";*/

}
```

Comment: a que te refieres con eliminar consulta?

Comment: Lo mismos iba a preguntarle @AlfredoPaz

Comment: por lo que veo en tu código estas invocando un procedimiento almacenado, pero fuera de eso no me queda claro lo demás

Comment: @AlfredoPaz osea datos, tengo una tabla llamada clientes, y quiero poder eliminar ciertos clientes desde mi pagina con php

Comment: entonces corrije tu título, por que eso no es lo que estas pidiendo

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que he visto en la respuesta que has dejado en los comentarios a lo que te refieres con eliminar consulta es a borrar un registro de la base de datos.

Te recomiendo que cambies el título de tu pregunta y tengas cuidado con los términos que utilizas en futuras consultas.

Para borrar un registro con PHP simplemente hay que ejecutar una consulta DELETE FROM y controlar los errores.

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tiendita";

// Creación de la conexión
$conexion = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Se comprueba la conexión realizada.
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Error en la conexión: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Consulta para borrar el dato que queramos. 
$sql = "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente=1";
//Ejecutamos la consulta y comprobamos que se haya completado correctamente.
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Registro borrado correctamente.";
} else {
    echo "Error al borrar el registro: " . $conn->error;
}
//Al acabar se cierra la conexión.
$conn->close();
?>
```

En la consulta `$sql = "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente=1";` tendrías que crear tu propia consulta para borrar el registro o registros en función del valor que quieras. Si quieres poder elegir de alguna manera la id de cliente a borrar desde la aplicación, tendrías que cambiar el `id_cliente=1` por alguna variable tipo `id_cliente=$idBorrar` y recuperarla desde un $_POST o similar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero, debes obtener el id que quieres eliminar de tu bd:

1. Crea una variable y dale el valor correspondiente:

   ```
   $idDelete = $_GET['id'];
   ```
2. Ahora que tienes el id, solo localizalo en tu sql.

   ```
   $borrar = "DELETE * FROM tutabla WHERE id = '$idDelete';";
   ```